# Nginx Reverse Proxy For Subdomain Not Working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup a self-hosted version of `GitLab` in a `Docker container`. The exposed ports of the container should only be accessible through a `reverse proxy` that is running on `nginx`. This way, I can manage my `ssl-certificates` consistently over all my `server blocks`.

As always, I added another server block (git.example.com) to the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory containing this configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name git.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80; # points to port 80 inside docker, which is web-interface
    }
}

# Note: strongly simplified version, problem still persists
```

When I `curl 127.0.0.1:80` on my server, I get the login page of GitLab, confirming that the container is in deed running correctly. But when I try to visit `git.example.com` the browser throws an `NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST` error.

I am still able to visit my homepage through example.com, as well as other subdomains like `files.example.com`, where the other subdomains have `ssl` enabled using certbot.

My DNS records:

| Type | Name | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CNAME | www | example.com |
| A | @ | *ip* |

What I tried:

- reloading nginx using `systemctl reload nginx`
- restarting system
- disabling `ufw` (firewall)

As I have very little experience, asking questions here, I will provide further information in the comment-section if requested.

Answer (score -1):

When using multiple subdomains with `nginx`, every subdomain has to get its own `A record`. An A record for a subdomain would look something like this:

| Type | Name | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | git | *ip* |

The reason why the other subdomains worked is, that I removed such A records a few hours ago, to test if the corresponding services would still be accessible. But I did not consider that a `DNS propagation` could take this long.